# Handling put requests in a React web application

Tags: reactjs, web, crud, put

I'm creating a web application with React where a user can keep track of collectable items. The React app will be connected to AWS via API Gateway, and will make requests which will be handled by Lambda's and the data store in a DynamoDB table. I am also making use of React Query to cache the data and minimise too many Lambda triggers to keep costs low.

Each item is rendered on a card, and the card will have a "-" and a "+" button, which the user can click to increase the quantity of said item in their collection/in the database. The most basic way to do this would be to make a put request every time either of the buttons are clicked, and updating the database accordingly. But this sounds extremely inefficient to me.

My question is, what is the best way to handle the put requests while minimising the number of API calls/Lambda triggers?

Answer (score 1):

You can debounce or throttle your requests to minimize the number of API calls so that a put request is made at regular intervals rather than on every button click.

Here’s a thorough guide for how to implement denouncing and throttling:

https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2022-03/debounce-vs-throttle/